# Автоматическая очистка кеша на сайте

Tags: php, кэширование

У меня есть сайт. И я хочу реализовать на нём автоматическую очистку кеша. Весь кеш сохраняется в определённую папку.

Как мне реализовать автоматическую очистку этой папки, скажем, каждые 24 часа.

Comment: Дополните вопрос, на него невозможно ответить однозначно, возможно вам нужно написать скрипт который будет удалять папку и периодически его запускать

Comment: установите задание по крону

Comment: @Ghost Такой способ решение проблемы подходит. Буду безмерно благодарен, если поможете с реализацией.

Comment: добавить в крон "rm -rf /путь/до/папки/*"  - осторожно, рекурсивно удаляет все и еще проверить права надо

Comment: @Ghost и команда я так понял удалит каталог который в пути указан, тоже?

Comment: @Ghost Собственно добавил я задачу в планировщик, но она не работает. Права поставил везде 755, так что по идее должно было работать

Comment: Правильно он делает, вы от себя задачу поставили, а Пых под отдельным пользователем работает, проще из под sudo поставить

Comment: @Ghost что-то я вас не очень понимаю, можете без сленга пожалуйста.